# port forwarded to my router but not forwarded to my pc

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I have forward a port to my router successfully but it is not forwarded to my PC.

My router is Dlink, DIR-600m, firmware version:-3.01 and the hardware version is C1.

I searched for a demonstration for port forwarding but I can't find anything that helps me.

I use following link to check my forwarded port: http://ping.eu/port-chk/

My firewall is off.

When I enter my router IP it shows the port is open but when I enter my pc IP it shows the port is closed.

Comment: When you set up port forwarding, you set that port forwarding up for a certain IP address. Did you apply that IP address to your PC?

Comment: "when I enter my pc IP it shows the port is closed." How did you test this? What do you have listening on the port?

Comment: usually you set up port forwarding BECAUSE you have something listening to it. If it's just to test how port-forwarding works, set up a simple web server and check if it's reachable from outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

You have an external IP (your router) and an internal IP (your pc).

1. Make sure you have entered the right internal IP and the right Port in your routers settings. Most routers use DHPC, then it might happen that your computer has a different IP now than before. The **internal** will most likely be "192.168.X.X".
2. A port checker tries to connect to a certain port, but can only do so when there is actually some program waiting for it by listening to that port. When it fails it can either mean that the Port is not forwarded - **OR** that nothing is listening! By the way: When using the tool above you should enter the **external** IP.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply and sorry for my poor english. Yes skjerns i enter right IP and right Port number in port number. actually at that time my office camera are seen in my mobile. because of enable DMZ on that ip instead of DMZ i want take it on port forwarding method.

Comment: So that means there is an application running on your computer that is waiting for someone to connect? And when you try to connect, it doesn't work?

Comment: yes right bro.how i solve it?